# Change of radio button after checking does not work at all

Tags: html, css, radio-button, checked

I want to make a quiz where radio-buttons change colors after being checked. I've created the following example but clicking does not change the background as intended.

HTML:

```
<div id="quiz">

      <input name="question_id" value="2" type="hidden">
      <ul class="list-inline">


            <label for="id_answers_0"><input id="id_answers_0" name="answers" value="5" type="radio"> None</label>



            <label for="id_answers_1"><input id="id_answers_1" name="answers" value="6" type="radio"> A little</label>



            <label for="id_answers_2"><input id="id_answers_2" name="answers" value="7" type="radio"> A lot</label>



            <label for="id_answers_3"><input id="id_answers_3" name="answers" value="8" type="radio"> Enormous</label>


      </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#quiz {
    margin:4px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding:13px 0px;
    width : 100%;


}

#quiz label {
    float:left;
    width:170px;
    padding : 5%;
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;

}

#quiz label:hover {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label{ background:black; }  


#quiz label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
```

}

Jsfiddle example :
http://jsfiddle.net/n5xb4b9v/

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example, http://jsfiddle.net/n5xb4b9v/3/

I changed the html to this

```
<div id="quiz">

      <input name="question_id" value="2" type="hidden">
      <ul class="list-inline">


            <input id="id_answers_0" name="answers" value="5" type="radio"><label for="id_answers_0"> None</label>



           <input id="id_answers_1" name="answers" value="6" type="radio"><label for="id_answers_1"> A little</label>



            <input id="id_answers_2" name="answers" value="7" type="radio"><label for="id_answers_2"> A lot</label>



            <input id="id_answers_3" name="answers" value="8" type="radio"><label for="id_answers_3"> Enormous</label>


      </ul>
</div>
```

And added this to your css

```
input[type=radio] {
   display: none;
 }
#quiz input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
   background-color: black;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, man, I don't align and comment code
Your main mistake - + in css
+ selector mean that:

tag1 + tag2 {
   styles
}

that means, tag2 will styled only when this tag will place after tag1 (not child)

```
<div id="quiz">
  <input name="question_id" value="2" type="hidden">
  <ul class="list-inline">  
       <input id="id_answers_0" name="answers" value="5" type="radio">   
         <label for="id_answers_0">None</label>

         <input id="id_answers_1" name="answers" value="6" type="radio">
         <label for="id_answers_1"> A little</label>

         <input id="id_answers_2" name="answers" value="7" type="radio">
         <label for="id_answers_2"> A lot</label>

         <input id="id_answers_3" name="answers" value="8" type="radio">
         <label for="id_answers_3"> Enormous</label>


  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/014kpxpz/